# How to select leaf tags of an html document using jsoup

Tags: javascript, html, jsoup

I am using jsoup to parse an html document. I need to extract all the child div elements. This is basically div tags without nested div tags. I used the following in  java to extract div tags,

```
Elements bodyTag = document.select("div:not(div>div)");
```

Here is an example:

```
<div id="header">
     <div class="container">
         <div id="header-logo"> 
         <a href="/" title="mekay.com">
             <div id="logo">
             </div> </a>
        </div>
        <div id="header-banner">
            <div data-type="ad" data-publisher="lqm.j2ee.site" data-zone="ron">
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

I need to extract only the following:

```
 <div id="logo">
 </div>
 <div data-type="ad" data-publisher="lqm.j2ee.site" data-zone="ron">
 </div>
```

Instead, the above code snippet is returning all the div tags. So, could you please help me figure out what is wrong with this selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is perfectly working

```
Elements innerMostDivs = doc.select("div:not(:has(div))");
```

Try it [online](http://try.jsoup.org/)

- add your html file
- add css query as `div:not(:has(div))`
- check resulted elements

Answer (score 0):

If you want only `div` leafs that do not have **any** children then use this

```
Elements emptyDivs = document.select("div:empty");
```

The selector you are using now means `fetch me all the divs that are not direct children of another div`. It is normal that it brings the very first parent div, because the `div id="header"` is not a direct child of a `div`. Most likely its parent is `body`.